# Does the HTML password field include any protection against XHR/AJAX exfiltration?

Tags: web-application, privacy, html, protection, ajax

In HTML when we describe a certain field as a password field is it somehow secured against sending out the data via XHR/AJAX/similar technologies?

This is relevant in case we have to deal with script injection and similar attacks.

According to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99596/html-password-fields) question the protection is done on the client-side and only protects against physical viewing of the password, is that correct? It's hard to tell from the lack of information and it is only a blind assumption.

P.S This question has nothing to do with locally stored passwords in the browser.

Comment: In fact, data in password fields is often sent over XHR, since many modern applications are heavily frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using type="password" in HTML *only* prevents shoulder-surfing by obscuring the typed characters on the screen.  The actual password is available to any code that can access the document object model, and, in the absence of a TLS connection, is sent to the server in the clear.

Although not directly related to the question, I have to add that "client-side encryption" is useless.  The "encrypted" value is available through the DOM, and as far as the server is concerned, that *is* the password.